# “Old school” Statistics probability question

Tags: probability, statistics

I was given this question from my statistics professor. He is looking for the tree diagram to show how many options their would be. Confused on how to get to the potential number of ways.

Old school prob question :
A restaurant offers a it’s patrons a choice of steak, chicken, or ham; if so desired red wine, white wine, or no wine may be ordered with the main course. It is known from experience that the probabilities that a customer will order steak,  chicken, or ham are 0.60, 0.30, 0.10. Also the probabilities that a customer will order red wine, white wine, or no wine after ordering steak is 0.40, 0.10, and 0.50 and the corresponding probabilities after selecting chicken are 0.05, 0.25, 0.70, and after ham are 0.15, 0.20, 0.65. Finally the probability that a customer leaves a good tip is 0.80 if He had steak and red wine, 0.30 if he had steak and white wine, and 0.60 steak and no wine  0.40,  if he had chicken and red wine 0.80, if he had chicken and white wine 0.70, if he had chicken and no wine  0.70 if he had ham and red wine .70 if he had ham and white wine, and .50 if had ham and no wine. What is the probability that a customer will leave a good tip?

Comment: Your first step would be to try to write this out using mathematical symbols rather than words. $P(A|B)$  is often used to notate [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S,C,H,R,W,N,G$ refer to the events where a customer orders steak, chicken, ham, redwine, whitewine, no wine, and leaves a good tip respectively.

Expand via [total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):

$$Pr(G)=Pr(G\mid R\cap S)Pr(R\mid S)Pr(S) + Pr(G\mid W\cap S)Pr(W\mid S)Pr(S) + Pr(G\mid N\cap S)Pr(N\mid S)Pr(S)+Pr(G\mid R\cap C)Pr(R\mid C)Pr(C)+\dots+Pr(G\mid N\cap H)Pr(N\mid H)Pr(H)$$

Each of these numbers above were given to you in the problem statement.

In other words, by having drawn a tree diagram we are calculating the probability of having arrived at each leaf node corresponding to having given a good tip by multiplying the probabilities of having traveled down each respective branch and then adding the final results.